# FreeType Glyph Metrics Caching of multiple Font sizes

Tags: c++, performance, unix, caching, freetype2

### Situation:

I have a project that renders product information onto a given template (custom XML format), then renders and converts it in a custom binary LCD format (steps simplified)

Our customers now want **auto-fitting text** container. (customer gives a **box of specific size** and all kinds of **strings have to get auto-resized** to **fit into that container**

For that I have to calculate the width of the string (freetype: each char/glyph) for multiple font-sizes (e.g. 100pt doesnt fit, 99pt doesnt fit, 98pt doesnt..., ..., 65pt fits!)

### Problem:

The Problem is that freetype takes a lot of time (~20-30 ms) for each auto-fit element and I have only ~100ms for my whole application to use. (so when customer adds 5 more autofit elements it's already guaranteed to exceed ~100 ms)

### Attempts:

A selfmade font-cache-generator which takes a font-file and calculates the widths of each unicode-character for font-sizes from 1pt to 100pt. Then it generates C source code out of the data like this:

```
//
#define  COUNT_SIZES  100    // Font-Size 1-100
#define  COUNT_CHARS  65536  // Full Unicode Table
int char_sizes[COUNT_SIZES][COUNT_CHARS] = 
{
   {1,1,2,2,3,1,1,2,2,3,1,2,2,1,2,2,3,1,2,.......// 65536
   {2,2,3,3,4,2,1,3,3,4,2,3,3,2,3,3,4,2,3,.......// 65536
   {2,3,4,3,5,2,2,4,4,5,2,4,4,2,4,3,5,3,3,.......// 65536
   // ...
   // 100 font sizes
};
```

That compiled in a dynamic lib (.so) is 25 MB in size and takes ~50ms to "dlload" and ~10ms to "dlsym" (WAAAAAAY too much!)

The same way but only ASCII table (so only 128 of 65536) compiles into a 58 KB .so file and takes ~500µs for "dlload" and ~100µs for "dlsym" (very nice!)

My next attempt would be to integrate the font-cache-generator into my project and cache only the glyphs I need for the specific customer (customer in europe needs ~500 glyphs, one in asia (e.g. traditional chinese) needs ~2500 (only examples, not exactly sure, maybe even more needed)

But before I take on that hard-work journey (:() I wanted to ask you if you know a better way of doing it? A library/project that does just that?

I cannot believe that it's not possible, how should a browser show lorem ipsum without loading seconds otherwise? :D

Any idea on how to solve this performance issue?

Any informative link on data caching with extremly fast access to cache (somewhat <1ms)?

### System Info:

- **Unix** (Ubuntu 16.04) **64bit**
- **x86** *AND* **arm** architectures exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one possible way using these libraries:

- **ICU** (for unicode)
- **Freetype** (for the Glyphs)
- **Harfbuzz** (for layout)

Github Project:
[Harfbuzz-ICU-Freetype](https://github.com/tangrams/harfbuzz-icu-freetype/tree/7c34b3c47da258879c00114cfe713e3c7aad5a99)

Loose build instructions:

- Search options in CMakeLists.txt `option(WITH_XX "DESCRIPT." ON/OFF)`
- Enable `CMake` options with `-D`: `cmake -DWITH_ZLIB=ON -DWITH_Harfbuzz=ON ..`
- `mkdir build && cd build && cmake [option [option [...]]] ..`
- `make -j $count_of_cpu_cores && sudo make install`

Google for some **Harfbuzz Layout tutorials / guides**