# Compiling freetype

Tags: freetype

While trying to compile freetype 2.6.1 on Ubuntu Linux 86-64, I get the following message at configure step:

```
/usr/local/include/harfbuzz/hb-common.h:316:29: note: in expansion of macro ‘HB_TAG_MAX’
   _HB_SCRIPT_MAX_VALUE    = HB_TAG_MAX, /*< skip >*/
                             ^
In file included from /home/sem/Downloads/freetype-2.6.1/freetype-2.6.1/src/autofit/afglobal.h:26:0,
                 from /home/sem/Downloads/freetype-2.6.1/freetype-2.6.1/src/autofit/afpic.c:23,
                 from /home/sem/Downloads/freetype-2.6.1/freetype-2.6.1/src/autofit/autofit.c:21:
/home/sem/Downloads/freetype-2.6.1/freetype-2.6.1/src/autofit/hbshim.h:31:19: fatal error: hb-ft.h: No such file or directory
 #include <hb-ft.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 8):

Building FreeType can be a bit of a hassle if you don't exactly know what you're doing and without much experience of the required build tools. I ran into this as well and ... then [got my experience](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44043170/3206306) with build tools :)

You are trying to build *FreeType* with *HarfBuzz* support. That, ofcourse, requires *HarfBuzz*. Actually you'd need a *FreeType-supported HarfBuzz* build (-> `hb-ft.h`) in order to build a *HarfBuzz-supported FreeType*

Here are 2 simple ways I get *FreeType* to compile *without Harfbuzz*:

by **configure**

```
git clone https://git.savannah.nongnu.org/git/freetype/freetype2.git
cd freetype2
./autogen.sh                   # generates configure
./configure --without-harfbuzz # generates Makefile + deactivates harfbuzz
make                           # compile libs
make install                   # install libs & headers
```

by **cmake**

```
git clone https://git.savannah.nongnu.org/git/freetype/freetype2.git
cd freetype2
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..      # generates Makefile + deactivates HarfBuzz if not found
make          # compile libs
make install  # install libs & headers
```

If you want a HarfBuzz supported FreeType build you might want to have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44043170/3206306)

Comment: Thanks!  cmake worked for me while configure did not.

Comment: Holy moly. Thank you for this! I tack-tacked a `--without-brotli` and BOOM it worked, after about 5 hours of installing 5 different versions, etc. I appreciate you.

Comment: Yeah, if you use the `configure` way, you have to manually disable all lib integrations which are not supported (or installed) by your system. `cmake` will automatically disable unsupported/uninstalled libs. At least AFAIK